# Input fields act weird on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 2 input fields aligned side by side. It works fine on desktop but on mobile they act weirdly. Below is my code and the screenshot on mobile. Can anyone perhaps help? Thanks in advance.

You can see it in action here: (the box in the footer is the problem)
https://www.wondercatspopup.com/hakkinda/

[image: screenshot]

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
  <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label style="display:none!important;" for="billing_first_name"><?php _e('First name', 'woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input style="width: 130px;
        display: inline-block; margin-right:1px;" type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text placeholder" placeholder="İsim *" type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['billing_first_name'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_first_name']); ?>"
    />


    <label style="display:none!important;" for="billing_last_name"><?php _e('Last name', 'woocommerce'); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input style="width: 130px;
        display: inline-block; margin-left:1px;" type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text placeholder" placeholder="Soyisim *" type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['billing_last_name'])) esc_attr_e($_POST['billing_last_name']); ?>"
    />
  </p>
</div>

<p style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 10px;" class="form-row form-row-wide">

  <label style="display:none!important;" for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
  <input style="width:274px!important;" type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text placeholder" placeholder="Cep Telefonu *" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>"
  />
</p><br>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `display:flex` at the first div. Remove that and the alignment issue should be fixed.

Comment: Ah it was that easy. Thank you!